# Rails: why would I want more than one ActionMailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Reading the [ActionMailer tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html), I'm kind of confused by the need to create a named mailer (`rails generate mailer UserMailer`).  Would I ever want more than one?  Why isn't there just a single global one?

Clearly I can just create a single mailer with an arbitrary name and get on with my life, but I'm worried that I'm missing something, ought I to be creating different mailers for different things?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the same reason you wouldn't want just one controller with 100 actions in it. If you only have one or two small things your site needs to use e-mail for, then one mailer would probably work fine. But if you have multiple e-mail-related components (for example, user registration/password management, newsletter subscriptions, notifications of events on the site, etc.) you may want to break those out into multiple mailers to help keep your code clean and structured.